# Trying to Use CFEXECUTE with Curl to Post via API to Rumble

Tags: api, curl, coldfusion

I am trying to convert this example script (from Rumble's Upload API) to  using CURL:

`curl -F "access_token=XXXXX" \ -F "title=A cool video" \ -F "description=Some detailed description" \ -F "license_type=0" \ -F "channel_id=123" \ -F "video=@video.mp4" \ -F "thumb=@thumbnail.jpg" \ "https://rumble.com/api/simple-upload.php"`

I've been trying to get the following code working to upload videos via API to our Rumble account.  I'm new to Curl and CFEXECUTE but not new to Coldfusion:

`<cfexecute name = "/usr/bin/curl" arguments = "-X POST --insecure https://rumble.com/api/simple-upload.php -F access_token=#access# -F title=#titletouse# - F description=#descript# -F license_type=0 -F channel_id=#channel# -F video=@#form.video#" variable="response" timeout = "999"> </cfexecute>`

Most of the time the response is: [empty string]

The variables listed are required.  I'm pretty sure it IS connecting to Rumble because I tried bunch of different versions and one was without POST and got back JSON response data and another was without an -F before description and got back: { "success": false, "errors": { "description": { "code": "MISSING_OR_INVALID_VALUE" } } }

For example, I tried:

with single quotes around each form field '-F license_type=0'
with -H 'Content-Type:multipart/form-data'
with semi colons between fields: -F licensetype=0;-F channel_id=#channel#

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?  I have tried about 30 different things.... and am out of ideas.  Thank you!!!!!

Comment: Why not use cfhttp?

Comment: It's to a https page and cfhttp didn't work -- ran into the issue with adding certificates, and, although I was able to add the certificate with keytool, the issue persisted.  I'd like to get Curl working so that I can use it for multiple api's to https pages.

Comment: If you're experienced with CF but not with cURL or cfexecute, then it would seem to make more sense to fix the certificate issue and use cfhttp. Cert issues are usually well-known and easy to resolve. With a cfexecute+cURL mashup you're more likely to be on your own. Checking the rumble endpoint with ssllabs shows their trust chain does not include any "extra downloads", and they even support TLS 1.0+1.1, so cfhttp should work even on old versions of CF+Java. Did you ensure that the Digicert intermediate cert was added too? Did you restart CF service afterwards? What was the error?

Comment: What version of CF? Running a test cfhttp call against that url did not throw a cert error using CF2018.  CFHttp is my preference as well, but if you must use cfexecute be sure to add something like `errorVariable` and dump the results, or else you might not know it if an error occurs.  (Also, I assume the `--insecure` option is just for testing purposes only?)

Comment: We're using cf9.  I will head back to the cfhttp route if I can't get curl to work, but really want to try this first as we've had persistent issues with the certificates for two other api's that we simply stopped using... I was able to get this working via ssh:  curl -F access_token=123xyz -F title='testtitle' -F channel_id=706227 -F description='testdescription' -F license_type=0 -F channel_id=706227 -F video=@'testvideo.mov' -ignore https://rumble.com/api/simple-upload.php    So, now I just need to translate that to cfexecute.

Comment: The first try didn't work:   <cfexecute
    name = "/usr/bin/curl"
    arguments = "-F access_token=xyz123 -F title='testtitle' -F channel_id=706227 -F description='testdescription' -F license_type=0 -F channel_id=706227 -F video=@'testvideo.mov' -ignore https://rumble.com/api/simple-upload.php"
    variable="response"
    timeout = "999">
</cfexecute>

Comment: Without lecturing on the risks of using an unsupported version of Adobe CF - using CF9 you'll hit problems with any API that requires TLS 1.2 or later, and you'll hit problems with any API that serves https using SNI, and if the API is using letsencrypt then their certs will be renewing regularly, requiring you to do the keytool import dance at least quarterly and probably more often. Upgrading to a recent version of ACF or Lucee would solve those problems.

Comment: ...and looking at the rumble cert, it looks like your issue will be because their certificate Subject/CN is for `*.rumble.com` , with SAN values for both `*.rumble.com` and `rumble.com`. You're trying to connect to `rumble.com`, but you cannot because it's not in the cert Subject, it's only in the SAN, and Adobe did not fix SAN support in cfhttp until CF10. If rumble's cert had `rumble.com` as their CN and `*.rumble.com` in the SAN, or if rumble gave access on a subdomain without redirecting, then even CF9 cfhttp could cope.

Comment: Appreciate the advice.  We're planning to switch to Lucee soon.  In the interim, I was able to get it working in case anyone else needs it in the future: <cfexecute
    name = "/usr/bin/curl"
    arguments = '-H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" --compression --insecure "https://rumble.com/api/simple-upload.php"
    -F "access_token=#access#" -F "title=#titletouse#" -F "description=#descript#" -F "license_type=0" -F "channel_id=#channel#" -F "video=@#form.video#"'
    variable="response"
       errorVariable = "errordata"
    timeout = "999">
</cfexecute>

Comment: This is on linux.. in case that makes any difference...

Comment: My mistake -- take out --compression

Comment: So the primary difference was adding the "Content-Type" header?  Also, be sure you actually need the `--insecure` option, as it seems to skip certificate validation. That can pose risks, depending on what info is transmitted.

Comment: say, can you tell me how you generated the `access_token` ? there's nothing on the internet about it, it's crazy how hard is it, even on Rumble itself there are no videos on how to use their own API